# Can I say that transporting data with usb is API?

Tags: api

I'm super new in Server Programming, and felling confused about exact concept of API.

As far as I know, API is interface about data usage between two or more systems. If so, Can I say that transporting data from USB to PC  is API too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An api is a bit different of a concept,
In an api you setup endpoints or connections that you are able to extract and submit data over. I wouldn't consider manual transfer over usb an api because you are unable to connect to the machine and make them communicate. Look into restapi design its a good way to grasp the concept better. [Rest Api Basics](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/)